# how can i simplify a loop

Tags: jquery, loops

Here is a for loop. I am trying to simplify it (as in downgrade and take out the loop(s) for ease of use).
Not sure how to--can someone explain?

```js
if (myBox.length >= i) {
    var smile = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < myBox[i].myRating; x++) {
        smile = smile + '<span>☺</span>';
    }
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + myBox[i].Title + smile + '</td><tr>');
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question???  And it looks like you are trying to set a `tr` as direct child of a `div` element. Of course this is invalid HTML markup.  EDIT: NO wait, your rendered HTML doesn't make any sense. You close a div before closing other opening tags

Comment: @vzupo, pay attention the code you wrote. I edited the malformed HTML, the selector `#div` seems to be a table, and you are closing a `<div>` that never was opened, and the `<tr>` never was closed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to downgrade, you need to start from the biggest value and run loop to '0'. If you wrote correctly, I presume the code will be like this

```
if (myBox.length >= i) {
var smile = '';
for (var x = myBox[i].myRating; x > 0; x--){
  smile = smile + '<span>☺</span>';
}
```

here's another sample for downgrade

```
for(var x=5; x>0; x--){
  console.log(x + ',');  //it'll print 5,4,3,2,1, in your console log
  //if you want to print 0 also, just use "x>=0" in the for loop
}
```

> And please post full code always

Comment: so say myBox.length only goes to 5 and myRating goes up to 5 as well, how do i completley get rid of the for loops

Comment: @vzupo Please be more specific. What you want to do?

Comment: i want myRating to represent the amount of smiles that display

Comment: var smile = '';
 for (var x=0; x < myRating; x++)
 {
  smile += '<span>@</span>';
 }
 $('div').append(smile);
seems your code is fine.. maybe you've wrote something wrong in other code

Comment: any way to do that not using a for loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid loops completely, but you could create a utility function that repeats strings for you, and call that instead.

```
function repeatStr(str, num)
{
    var returnStr = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
      returnStr += str;
    }

    return returnStr;
}
```

and then in your code:

```
if (myBox.length >= i) {
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + myBox[i].Title + repeatStr('<span>☺</span>', myBox[i].myRating) + '</td></tr>');
}
```